# problems scraping (access denied)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to retrieve all the infos in a site (I deleted the link because yesterday someone closed my question).

I've been working on it for two weeks, and three days ago, when entering the site directly from Chrome, it  asked me to check if I was a robot, because saw strange movements from my IP. ( I don't remember exactly what was written but that was the concept).

Today I was working and extracting some data ( a simple list of links) and at my second run of the code, I notice that the list was empty. so I check looking at the result of `requests.get('**site**')` and it was different from the html of the page that I usually was looking at these days.

Finally I tried to go on the site directly from the browser, and it opens me the page of the site, but just empty with **"Access Denied"** written.

I still tried to add the user-agent at the request row, but continues to give me access denied. here a simple script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('site', headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) Gecko/20100101 Chrome/72.0.3626.121'}).text
obj = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
print(obj)
```

this below is the output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<title>AZLyrics - request for access</title>
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/bsaz.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script async="" defer="" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
      if (top.location != self.location) {
      top.location = self.location.href
     }
    //--> 
    function az_recaptcha_success(){
        document.getElementById("az_unblock").submit();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top text-center">
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="navbar-header" style="float:none; display:inline-block;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.azlyrics.com"><img alt="AZLyrics.com" class="pull-left" src="/az_logo_tr.png" style="max-height:40px; margin-top:-10px;"/></a>
</div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- top ban -->
<!--  <div class="lboard-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 top-ad text-center">
         <span id="cf_banner_top_nofc"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> -->
<!-- main -->
<div class="container main-page">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                Access denied.
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
 <!-- container main-page -->
<!-- bot ban -->
<!--<div class="lboard-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 top-ad text-center">
          <span id="cf_banner_bottom"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>-->
<!-- footer -->
<!--<nav class="navbar navbar-footer">
          <div class="container text-center">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
            <li><a href="//www.azlyrics.com/adv.html">Advertise Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="//www.azlyrics.com/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="//www.azlyrics.com/cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="//www.azlyrics.com/copyright.html">DMCA Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div> 
     </nav>-->
<div class="footer-wrap">
<div class="container">
<small>
<script type="text/javascript">
                curdate=new Date();
                document.write("<strong>Copyright &copy; 2000-"+curdate.getFullYear()+" AZLyrics.com<\/strong>");
             </script>
</small>
</div>
</div>
```

Do you think there is something I can do to continue working on this site?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Pleas not to close your question are more likely to generate downvotes and close votes than help you. Your best bet is to simply ask a good question.

Comment: Your problem seems not to be about code as that your target website has implemented ant-scraping and decided that you are scraping. Have you checked their terms of service allow you to scrape their data? Voted to close.

Comment: @Chris I'm correcting my question, can you tell me what's wrong in it? I'm reading <2how to ask" page but I'm not sure what to change here.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there doesn't seem to be any actual answer for this question, here goes:

As has been pointed out in the comments above, the particular site being scraped in this case uses anti-scraping - i.e. it detects "overuse" (by some definition of overuse). When overuse is detected, it can then block access to the IP address which was used.

A workaround would be to use another IP address (or many different IP addresses, e.g. via VPNs or proxies).